# How to remove first two letters of every columns in R?

Tags: r

My data frame looks:

```
Sdate       Edate    NY_Close_40   NY_High_40
2020-1-3  2020-1-5        20          30
```

I want to remove "NY_" in every column. I tried by writing

```
sub("NY_*", "", df[,1])
```

but my entire data frame is gone. Column names that I want to have is:

```
Sdate   Edate   Close_40   High_40
```

What should I change to do it?

Comment: You just want to alter the column names, right? Then you can do: `colnames(df) <- sub("NY_*", "", colnames(df))`

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen Yes, I want to remove "NY_" and keep others. My data frame is gone with the code you wrote. What is wrong?

Comment: Please add `dput(head(df))` to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
names(df) = gsub("NY_", "", names(df))
```

This will replace `NY_` with an empty string for all column names in `df`.

What you are trying to do is to replace `NY_` in the first column, not the first column name.

Comment: Thank you J.C.Wahl, but I got an error, "cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character' " What is wrong in my data frame?

Comment: Can you post your data? Do you have a data frame named `df`?

Comment: It is too big to post here, but it looks exactly like I posted above. Do you need to see the details?